# Oracle insert in index table:Time to load 500 thousand rows is more than inserting 16 million rows

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, oracle9i

At first I tried normal insert into target table from temporary table.

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO RDW10DM.INV_ITEM_LW_DM
SELECT
    *
FROM
    RDW10PRD.TMP_MDS_RECLS_INV_ITEM_LW_DM
;
COMMIT;
```

It tooks only 17 min to load.Total count in temp table TMP_MDS_RECLS_INV_ITEM_LW_DM is 16491650.
Plan for Execution:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            |  Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT     |                               |    16M|  1290M|  4927 |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT      |                               |       |       |       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TMP_MDS_RECLS_INV_ITEM_LW_DM  |    16M|  1290M|  4927 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: cpu costing is off
```

Then I tried to load loc wise:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO RDW10DM.INV_ITEM_LW_DM
SELECT
        *
FROM
     RDW10PRD.TMP_MDS_RECLS_INV_ITEM_LW_DM
     where LOC_KEY=222
;
COMMIT;
```

Then it tooks around 28 min to load. Total count in temp table with filter is 493465

Plan for execution:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            |  Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT     |                               |   492K|    38M|  4927 |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT      |                               |       |       |       |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TMP_MDS_RECLS_INV_ITEM_LW_DM  |   492K|    38M|  4927 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("TMP_MDS_RECLS_INV_ITEM_LW_DM"."LOC_KEY"=222)

Note: cpu costing is off
```

Index in Target table:
[image]

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Execution plans for the queries?

Comment: Execution plans updated

Comment: Are there indexes present on the TEMP table or on the table being updated?

Comment: There isn't index in temp table.

Comment: cpu costing is off? Might like to investigate that. What version is this?

Comment: I'd guess this issue is caused by caching or system activity.  If the execution plan operations are the same, and the only difference is a simple filter, there's no reason for the second plan to be noticeably slower.  Can you re-run the two INSERTs multiple times and see if they are still different?

Comment: @Job Heller thanks for you thought. Later I found that I have to rebuild index. Since I have doing frequent truncate and load in this table, index pages might have fragmented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone for your valuable thoughts.

I found the actual problem later. Since I have doing frequent truncate and load in target table RDW10DM.INV_ITEM_LW_DM so index pages might have fragmented.
So, ran query after rebuilding indexes and got expected results.

Answer (score 0):

My guess? The TMP table doesn't have an index.

Therefore - selecting all records and inserting them is faster then applying an a filter on 16Mil records.

As you can see, in your second execution plan the scanner is using `FULL ACCESS` , which slows down the query. Try adding an index on `TMP_MDS_RECLS_INV_ITEM_LW_DM(LOC_KEY)` . It should boost your query performance.

Comment: Thanks, I will add index and view execution plan.

Comment: Let me know if it helped @DineshSubedi

Comment: Sounds hopeful, if there really are ~500k rows out of 16m that meet the condition.